Select column name that has the maximum value -- Convert PostgreSQL query to Oracle?
Table name: employment_by_industry

For each row, I want to select the column name that has the maximum value:


I'm looking for succinct ways to do that in Oracle, with the column names only being listed once in the SQL query.
Here is a PostgreSQL technique:
select objectid, (SELECT industry FROM (values 
       (agr_forest_fish, 'agr_forest_fish'),
       (mining_quarry, 'mining_quarry'),
       (mfg, 'mfg'),
       (electric, 'electric'),
       (water_sew, 'water_sew')
  ) as t(emp, industry)
  order by emp DESC
  LIMIT 1)
from employment_by_industry

I suppose the column names are listed more than once. But maybe it's good enough.
Source
https://dbfiddle.uk/ZdJhvNZC
Can the PostgreSQL query be adapted to work in Oracle? (any version)

What to do if multiple columns have the same highest value?

@JonasMetzler Choosing an arbitrary value/column name is fine.

On Oracle, assuming each row would always have just a single maximum employment value, we can use a GREATEST() trick here:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*,
        GREATEST(agr_forest_fish, mining_quarry, mfg, electric, water_sew) AS max_val
    FROM employment_by_industry t
)

SELECT
    objectid,
    CASE WHEN agr_forest_fish = max_val THEN 'agr_forest_fish'
         WHEN mining_quarry = max_val THEN 'mining_quarry'
         WHEN mfg = max_val THEN 'mfg'
         WHEN electric = max_val THEN 'electric'
         WHEN water_sew = max_val THEN 'water_sew' END AS industry
FROM cte
ORDER BY objectid;


You can simplify that writing ...CASE max_val WHEN agr_forest_fish THEN 'agr_forest_fish' WHEN mining_quarry THEN 'mining_quarry'...
